# Firebase database set objects in favorite list

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a problem clearing list in fragments. I need to clear the list when happening update in fragment. I already put it in different places but it does not help me.

When an update happens in fragment it shows the same list but that list also add elements from the previous list. If I put `list.clear()`; in the moment when it rakes arguments from firebase it did not give me needed effect, when I put it in onCreate() method then app gives me error.

```
public class Favourite extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<TourReader1> artistList;
private ToursAdapter1 adapter1;
private DatabaseReference reference,reference2;
String uid;

public Favourite() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    //Get current user id
    uid = user.getUid();
    //Connect to specific point in database Tours
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tours");
    //Create add to method valuelistener or reference which is specific point in database
    reference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(uid);
    reference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    reference.keepSynced(true);

}
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = (new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot1) {
            //get all information from specific point of database
            for (DataSnapshot datasnapshot : snapshot1.getChildren()) {
                //get current name of starting point from where we recive information from database
                String firstname = datasnapshot.getKey();
                //valuelistener for another point from database
                reference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot2:snapshot.getChildren()){
                                String seconame = dSnapshot2.getKey();
                                Boolean control = dSnapshot2.child("like").getValue(Boolean.class);
                                if(control != null&&firstname.equals(seconame) &&control.equals(true)) {
                                    TourReader1 artist = datasnapshot.getValue(TourReader1.class);
                                    artistList.add(artist);
                                }
                            }
                        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    artistList = new ArrayList<>();
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favourite, container, false);
    recyclerView = rootview.findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    adapter1 = new ToursAdapter1(getContext(), artistList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
    return rootview;
}
```

}

Comment: it's a little confusing to understand your requirement, can you please let me know in non-technical terms what behaviour you are expecting?

Comment: I take list of tours from firebase and compare it with another where is written if user put like on this tour or not. If like is true then this tour go to favourite tours list. Problem is when user unlike tour on favourite tours screen list updates but there is also elemtns from previous list. My problem is in clearing list from ol elements.

Comment: Have you tried @dinkar_kumar answer? Does it work?

Comment: Nope, I put it before loop and add adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged(); but this not work

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer myself, I clear my list in the adapter by `tourlist.clear(`) and remove `userpoints.keepSynced(true)`; when like icon is false.

```
holder.sparkButton.setEventListener(new SparkEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(ImageView button, boolean buttonState) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            String uid = user.getUid();
            DatabaseReference userpoints  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(uid);
            ToursLike registerDatabase = new ToursLike(true);
            if(buttonState){
                userpoints.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(tour.Name)) {
                            userpoints.child(tour.Name).setValue(registerDatabase);
                            userpoints.keepSynced(true);
                            tourList.clear();
                        }
                        else{
                            userpoints.child(tour.Name).child("like").setValue(true);
                            userpoints.keepSynced(true);
                            tourList.clear();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
            else{
                userpoints.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        userpoints.child(tour.Name).child("like").setValue(false);
                        tourList.clear();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onEventAnimationEnd(ImageView button, boolean buttonState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEventAnimationStart(ImageView button, boolean buttonState) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the artistList using artistList.clear() before your for loop in `onDataChange`as this list is having the data from the last callback triggered.